# Waiting to load results until search using filterrific

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filterrific

Does anybody know a way to make filterrific hold results until the user begins a search?

By default, filterrific displays unfiltered, paginated results to the user but I only need results once the user starts to type in the search query field.

[Default filterrific gem behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlwWJ.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Kindly provide details of how you have tried to solve the problem. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reworked example from the gem documentation. The concept is to return empty array if there is no search params for filterrific.

```
def index
  @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
    Student,
    params[:filterrific]
  ) 

  @students = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page]) if params[:filterrific].present?
    @students = [] if params[:filterrific].blank?

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```